# libpoppler-qt4: How to save form changes

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, poppler

I'm using libpoppler with the included qt bindings to edit forms in a PDF file.

```
// sample code
Poppler::Document* doc = Poppler::Document::load(filename);
Poppler::Page* page = doc->page(0);
QList<Poppler::FormField *> forms = page->formFields();
for(int j = 0; j < forms.length(); j++) {
    Poppler::FormField * form = forms.at(j);
    // fill it out or whatever...
    ...
```

But how can i save the changes made to a file? I know that poppler offers this possibility, eg for the Glib bindings: [poppler_document_save()](http://people.freedesktop.org/~ajohnson/docs/poppler-glib/PopplerDocument.html#poppler-document-save). How do I do this with the QT bindings? There's no `Poppler::Document::save()` method or anything, what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it out by myself after some digging in the [Okular source](http://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/okular/development): One has to use the `Poppler::PDFConverter` class. Below provided is a sample method:

```
bool saveToFile(const QString &filename, const Poppler::Document* doc) {
    Poppler::PDFConverter *pdfConv = doc->pdfConverter();
    pdfConv->setOutputFileName(filename);
    pdfConv->setPDFOptions(pdfConv->pdfOptions()|Poppler::PDFConverter::WithChanges);
    bool success = pdfConv->convert();
    delete pdfConv;

    return success;
}
```